# t-sql select stuff limit

Tags: sql-server, json, ssms

I have fetched values from a table, and I need to create a JSON from them.
When I use a few fields (smalll strings), JSON is valid, full set of data inserted into it.

```
set @MediaType = '['
```

When I use full set of fields, some of them are varchar(max), and placeholder for a result is varchar(max), only ~45k chars are returned.

```
select @JSON = 
    (
    select '{' + STUFF((
            select 
                @dSQL
                + ',"Name":"' +  rtrim(@Name) + '"'
                --+ ',"Name":"LOLLOLOLOLTROLOLOLo"'
                + ',"Descr":"' + rtrim(replace(coalesce(@Descr,''),'"','''''')) + '"'
                --+ ',"Descr":"' +  'Zvezda, Zvezda! '  + '"'
                --+ ',"Tech":"' +  replace(coalesce(@Tech,''),'"','''''') + '"'
                + ',"Tech":"' +  'Nije, nego Dinamooooo, o Dinamoooo! '  + '"'
                + ',"update_id":"' +  rtrim(@update_id) + '"'
                + ''
            for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + '}'
    )
```

Every fetch from cursor generates one "{...}", and latter I use

```
set @MediaType = (select (@MediaType + @JSON + ','))
```

Also,

```
set @MediaType = (select SUBSTRING(@MediaType, 1, (len(@MediaType)-1)))
set @MediaType = (select (@MediaType + ']'))
```

If I use short strings as Descr and Tech, everything is fine, but when I use real data from a table (@Descr and @Tech, declared as varchar(max), @MediaType is only under 50k chars?

(I believe that there is a better ways of doing it, and i have beautifull python code for that, but I have to do it in t-sql and I am by no means  expert, as you can see)

Thx

Comment: One thing that can definitely help in long term is brevity in name object properties like use N for name, D for descr, T for tech and U for update_id

Comment: You don't have sql server 2016 by any chance? That should have a build in `for Json` clause (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921882.aspx )

Comment: @DhruvJoshi, thank you for a suggestion. It is a legacy code, and I have rewritten code in python, but there are cases when I can't run it with xp_cmdshell. I'll try to rewrite this one too...

Comment: @Me.Name, no, and there are even instances with 2005 where I need to run this (or modified) code...